# Reinstalling AHCI SATA drivers after BIOS update?

Tags: windows-vista, bios, sata, ahci

I recently built a new PC and after installing Windows Vista x64 found that there were some overclocking features missing in the BIOS that could be enabled with a BIOS update.  I ran the update successfully but now the PC doesn't load Windows and displays the error:

"Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

I believe this has something to do with the Intel Matrix Storage Manager drivers but I'm not sure how to get those installed.  I can load the Windows install disc and I've tried to repair Windows but it was unsuccessful.  I also tried loading drivers from another CD within the Vista setup but I get an error.  I can get to the command prompt but am not sure how to manually install the drivers or if I even have the correct ones.

The drive with Windows installed on it is an 80GB Intel SSD.  I can see the drive and contents from the command prompt, but it is showing up as D:\ and my storage HDD is showing up as C:\, where previously they were the other way around.  It's also just showing up as "Removable Device" in the bios, while the storage drive shows up correctly as "WD 500gb..etc."

I'd prefer to not have to reinstall if possible.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  The issue was an oversight on my part.

After the BIOS update, the drive letters were switched (as mentioned in the question) so it was trying to load Windows from my storage drive and not the SSD.  After digging through the BIOS I found the setting to change them which resolved the issue.